# Please recommend a form like Google form to add calculations and if else logic when a user submits data

Tags: google-forms, calculator

Say I want two values from the end user X and Y. I want to calculate values like X*Y and logic like if X*Y < something then one value otherwise another value.

Comment: please add more information (examples, already tested results...) to your question if you want an answer

Comment: Please note that questions asking for recommendations are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

not sure which logic you need:

- **`=IF(A1="X";"X";"Y")`**
- **`=IF(SUM(A1:A2)<5;"X";"Y")`**

Comment: Is it possible in google form?

Comment: @Shreya if by "google form" you mean "google spreadsheet" then yes. otherwise not